# Problema ao desativar botão no primefaces

Tags: jsf-2.2, primefaces

Estou tentando realizar uma lógica de efetuar que o botão de exportar `excel` fique desativado ao usuário clicar no botão de pesquisar, caso o numero de registros seja igual a zero. O problema é que na primeira vez ele funciona normal, mas na segunda vez o botão já não é renderizado novamente.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="text-align: right" colspan="4">
            <p:commandButton id="bt_filtrar" value="#{lbl['BOTAO.FILTRAR']}" process="filtro" actionListener="#{propostaCartaoListBean.buscar}" update="tabela br_exportar"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <p:commandButton id="bt_limpar" icon="botaoLimpar" title="#{lbl['BOTAO.LIMPAR']}"/>
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton id="bt_exportar" icon="botaoExcel" ajax="false" disabled="#{propostaCartaoListBean.lazyModel.rowCount == 0}" title="#{lbl['BOTAO.EXPORTAREXCEL']}">
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tabela" fileName="propostaCartao" />  
            </p:commandButton>                                  
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</f:facet>
```

Este botão se encontra ao final de um `panelGrid` e acima de um `datatable`.

Como fazer para resolver este problema de perder a renderização do componente?

Comment: Experimente trocar isso: `propostaCartaoListBean.lazyModel.rowCount == 0` por um método novo no seu ViewBean que faça este teste e coloque um breakpoint dentro deste método. Veja o que acontece.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez irei testar e lhe aviso.

Comment: Qual a saída HTML de `propostaCartaoListBean.lazyModel.rowCount == 0`?

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira olhando por agora, quando eu comparo retorna `true` mas aparece registros no `dataTable`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é muito estranho mas o `lazyModel.rowCount` retorna 0 mas mostra valores no dataTable

Comment: @Macario1983 Significa que ele não é confiável. Recomendo que o teste seja trocado.

Comment: Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal um colega do trabalho me apresentou a uma solução viável para este problema.

```
<p:commandButton id="bt_filtrar" value="#{lbl['BOTAO.FILTRAR']}" 
    process="filtro"
    actionListener="#{propostaCartaoListBean.buscar}"
    update="tabela" oncomplete="atualizaBtnExportar()"/>

<p:commandButton id="bt_exportar" icon="botaoExcel" ajax="false" title="#{lbl['BOTAO.EXPORTAREXCEL']}" disabled="#{propostaCartaoListBean.lazyModel.rowCount == 0}">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tabela" fileName="propostaCartao" />  
</p:commandButton>

<p:remoteCommand name="atualizaBtnExportar" update="bt_exportar"/>
```

Ao utilizar esta tag `p:remoteCommand` ele faz o redirecionamento para processar o que quero.

Ou seja assim ele atualiza ao completar a ação no botão de filtrar e chama o componente.

Mas caso algum colega saiba, acho que tem nível de processamento do `ajax` do tipo, antes, durante e depois do ajax acontecer.